# Xml - put two images on top of each other

Tags: android, xml

If I have this xml-file which refers to imageresources

```
  <array name="cities_imgs">
    <item>@drawable/map_ayutthaya</item>
    <item>@drawable/ayutthaya1</item>
    <item>@drawable/ayutthaya2</item>
    <item>@drawable/ayutthaya3</item>
    <item>@drawable/ayutthaya5</item>
    .....
```

Is it possible to put two images on top of each other? For instance

```
 <item>@drawable/map_ayutthaya</item>
 <item>@drawable/position</item>
```

something like this

```
<array name="cities_imgs">
 <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item> @drawable/map_ayutthaya<item/>
    <item> @drawable/position<item/>
 </layer-list>
 .....
```